# Why is the local host 0 is not changing 1,2,3

Tags: reactjs

I am now writing code in React.
Actually, on the localhost page, when I click on the 'Search' button, the zero sign should change to 1,2,3,4,5... but nothing is changing. Please help me fix the code.
Eternally grateful

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have set onClick event on h1 and not on search button. Also, this is a very low quality question. You should read section on how to ask good question on Stack overflow

Comment: instead of putting code photos, just copy and paste the full code or relevant detailed sections in the question itself. you can also put it in a code sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Your `onClick` event should be added to the button inside the forms tags.